# How to save and load a class that contains a list of another class?

Tags: java

I had a class Inventory that contains a list of Treasure class. I designed the Reader to read the Inventory as a list of Treasure, but when I want to call the reader from my main function, it says that Inventory is not the same as a list of Treasure. And now I don't know what should I do, should I change the read method to only read Inventory, but then again Inventory contains all the list of Treasure that I need. I am very lost as how to do it.

```
public class Inventory implements SavedGames {
    private ArrayList<Treasure> inventory;
    private static Inventory instance;

    // EFFECTS: constructs an empty player inventory
    private Inventory() {
        this.inventory = new ArrayList<Treasure>();
        inventory.add(new Treasure("Potion", 4));
    }



    private void loadGames() {
        try {
            MainCharacter character = Reader.readCharacter(new File(CHARACTER_FILE));
            Monster monster = Reader.readMonster(new File(MONSTER_FILE));
            List<Treasure> inventory = Reader.readInventory(new File(INVENTORY_FILE));
            this.character = character;
            this.monster = monster;
            this.inventory = inventory;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read files, resetting...");
            startApp();
        }
    }





    private static List<Treasure> parseInventory(List<String> fileContent) {
        List<Treasure> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String line : fileContent) {
            ArrayList<String> lineComponents = splitString(line);
            inventory.add(parseTreasure(lineComponents));
        }

        return inventory;
    }

    private static Treasure parseTreasure(List<String> components) {

        String description = components.get(0);
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(components.get(1));
        return new Treasure(description, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted so far looks ok, where does the actual error occur? How is the main method calling your Reader?

Comment: Unless you declared your inventory class like this: `class Inventory implements List<Treasure>` then your Inventory class isn't a `List` of `Treasure`s. It is an object that *has* a `List` of `Treasure`s.

Comment: To offer more help, you will need to show us the actual code that throws the error. Don't describe what happens in your `main` method, show us.

Comment: I edit a little bit of my files, sorry this is the first time I ever posted a question so if there is any more information needed I will add them

Comment: @Twoface There are a few ways you can go about this. The way I would recommend is, unless the object has unique data such as player character with their own name and level, it's effective to give objects a unique ID and use that ID to recreate the objects on load. So as a simple example, you take all the IDs of Items in a player's inventory then store that info to a text or binary file. Then when loading, you pull that collection of IDs and use them to create the Item objects.

Comment: If you really want to make working with the data easy on yourself, I would recommend looking into using a data format like [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_json.asp) via a library like [JSON-Simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) which makes reading/writing and data parsing much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is a mechanism of converting the state of an object into a byte stream. Deserialization is the reverse process where the byte stream is used to recreate the actual Java object in memory. This mechanism is used to persist the object.
The byte stream created is platform independent. So, the object serialized on one platform can be deserialized on a different platform.

To make a Java object serializable we implement the java.io.Serializable interface.
The ObjectOutputStream class contains writeObject() method for serializing an Object.

```
public final void writeObject(Object obj)
                       throws IOException
```

The ObjectInputStream class contains readObject() method for deserializing an object.

```
public final Object readObject()
                  throws IOException,
               ClassNotFoundException
```